# How to batch process overlaying of different images to a directory of images?

Tags: batch, images, overlay

Folder1 has some images in png format and Folder2  has same number (& names) of images in png format with a watermark and transparency. I would like to overlay images from folder2 on images of folder1 with the same name eg. image1.png from Folder2 overlays image1.png of Folder1, image2.png from Folder2 overlays image2.png of Folder1, and so on. 
Is this possible with any software or script? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) program can do this.

Here is a loop that should when run in one of the folders (since the files are named identically in both folders) put the watermarks from Folder2 on the images in Folder1, and saving the result by putting a "w-" in front of the file name in the current folder.

```
for %%i in (*) do convert.exe ../Folder1/%%i ../Folder2/%%i -gravity center -composite w-%%i
```

I can't test it right now so you may need to adjust it to work.

[Here](https://www.xoogu.com/2013/how-to-automatically-watermark-or-batch-watermark-photos-using-imagemagick/) is a good post with other examples.

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution! I guess I have to install VISUAL STUDIO IDE because I am on Windows. Would appreciate a simpler solution without installation of many softwares though. (..although this seems to be as simple as it can get :))